# Python: How to convert string time to decimal seconds?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-datetime

```
String Time 
00:51:21,920

Decimal Time
3,081.92 (second)
```

Is there anyway that can convert between string time and decimal time in seconds? I want to use it in moviepy VideoFileClip.subclip.

Below is what I have done and it works. But I assume there should be an easier way like a function in a library.

```
def TrsTime(VideoTime):
  return (datetime.strptime(VideoTime, '%H:%M:%S,%f').hour*60*60+
  datetime.strptime(VideoTime, '%H:%M:%S,%f').minute*60+
  datetime.strptime(VideoTime, '%H:%M:%S,%f').second+
  datetime.strptime(VideoTime, '%H:%M:%S,%f').microsecond/1000/1000)
```

Comment: You should add what You have tried and read how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a simpler way:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

(dt.strptime(VideoTime, '%H:%M:%S,%f') - dt(1900, 1, 1)).total_seconds()

>>> 3081.92
```

This works on the principal that the `timedelta` object has a `.total_seconds()` function.  So by subtracting your time (whose year, month, day defaults to 1 Jan 1900) from 1 Jan 1900, you get the delta in seconds.